# Adding 3 years to a timestamp

Tags: timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have a timestamp that is fetched from the database. Now I have to add 3 years to it.

1. Is it possible to add 3 years in timestamp itself and then
   converting the date and time format ?
2. or after converting into the date and time format we can add?

How to add 3 years with respect to leap year and all those?

Comment: What programming language are you using? What database? What have you tried so far? Please extend your question.

Answer (score 2):

For every non-leap year, add `365 * 86400` = `31536000`.

For every leap year, add `366 * 86400` = `31622400`.